# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE errno 1 when npm install on a module

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm install
```

> hi-activate-tenant@2.2.0 install
>   C:\Santhosh\DevCentre\node8\BI-GIT-MASTER\hi-activate-tenant 
>   ./install.js
>
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! hi-activate-tenant@2.2.0 install: `./install.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the hi-activate-tenant@2.2.0 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.

I have already tried almost all the solutions like

```
npm cache clean --force
```

removing `node_modules`

and again `npm install`

please help me !!!

Answer (score 3):

Adding **node** in front of the script commands should work. So it should be like:

```
node ./install.js
```

Comment: it works perfectly on windows powershell, but not on git bash.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for the above issue :

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This error was due to the path failure.

In the package.json file for the install script it was given as './install.js 
change it to '.\install.js' and the fix works fine.

run an npm install now and the install will be successful without ant errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
I had this issue when tried to run package.json which was developed for linux systems and your answer helped!!!